# toggle is not working

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
  $("p").toggle(function(){
    $("p").hide();},
    function(){
     $("p").show();}

  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click me to toggle between different background colors.</p>
<button>click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to toggle between hide and show on button click...but it's not working
a little help will be appreciable

Comment: the toggle includes the act of hide and show, i think its better if you write it as $('p').toggle('slow');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `SyntaxError`. Don't forget to close the parenthesis after the closing brace of `toggle()`.

If you are only toggling the visibility of the element, you should just be able to use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) with no arguments.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M7dpB/).

Answer (score 0):

To toggle the background color use `toggleClass()` and CSS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("p").toggleClass('red');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M7dpB/1/

See the manual http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/h45En/

```
$('a').bind('click', function() {
    $('p').toggle();
});
```

toggle will hide the $('p') by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can write simply:

```
$("button").toggle(function(){
    $("p").hide();},
    function(){
    $("p").show();}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                    $("p").toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click me to toggle between different background colors.</p>
        <button>click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```